# How do I open all files of a commit in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I open all files edited in a commit in the editor window? I know I can see files of a commit in Source Control -> Commits section. But is there a shortcut?

Edit: I found that I can open them buy clicking on commit message and right click then Open Changes -> Open Files.

Is there a way I can make shortcut for it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the commit pane in the version control panel:

1. Right click on the Commit
2. Open Changes
3. Open Files

The command from the command pallet is `git: open changes` you can [assign](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) commands to key bindings.

With the [gitlens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) extension installed `GitLens: Open Changed Files` is probably what you're after?

Comment: how did you find the commands attached to these operations?

Comment: Press F1 to open the command pallet and type "open changes" or "git" and it searches all nested commads.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can do this through the command line:

```
code $(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD)
```

This will open all of the files in the most recent commit that you have checked out. The git command gets the diff of HEAD, suppresses commit id, only logs the name of the files, and opens them all using the `code` command, assuming you have that installed

Comment: `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD` does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this command from a shell

`code $(git diff --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD)`

Answer (score 0):

At least for changes that are not *yet* committed, **for keybindings, the command ID you want is `git.openAllChanges`** (the command's name is `Git: Open All Changes`). You can add a keyboard shortcut binding in the keyboard shortcuts UI (run `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)), or in the keybindings.json file (`Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`). See also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings.

Note that VS Code 1.85 added a feature to open an overview diff of all changes in a *single* editor tab ("multi-diff editor"). See [related release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85#_multifile-diff-editor) and [related issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179000).

For changes in previous commits, you'll probably need an extension like GitLens (I have no affiliation with that extension).